# Eclipse : fatal error in JeasyOpc

Tags: java, eclipse, jeasyopc

I am working with the last version of JeasyOpc on a server OPC RSLINX passing information of each tag to a database. Everything works fine, but it falls on the day of running, this depends of the workload. I know i need to handle well the memories, i have tried to optimize, but i need the advice of someone more experienced in java or Jeasyopc. pd. I changee the jre for the 1.7 . this is the log file. Thanks .

```
  #
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#enter code here
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x03d337d9, pid=4456, tid=5864
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x637d9]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03573400):  JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_in_native, id=5864, stack(0x03e50000,0x03ea0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xc503d337

Registers:
EAX=0x03d55f04, EBX=0xc503d337, ECX=0x03d55f37, EDX=0x03d3a501
ESP=0x03e9f828, EBP=0x03e9f858, ESI=0x0355d9cc, EDI=0x00000007
EIP=0x03d337d9, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x03e9f828)
0x03e9f828:   03cd31cf 03d36eb5 03573400 14eb7f58
0x03e9f838:   00000001 034cb23c 00000001 00000001
0x03e9f848:   0355d9c0 03d55f84 03d55f94 0355d9d8
0x03e9f858:   03e9f878 00b38492 035734f4 03e9f868
0x03e9f868:   14eb7f58 14eb7f58 14eb7f58 00000001
0x03e9f878:   03e9f968 00b45808 00000014 00000000
0x03e9f888:   03e9f8c8 7c91e900 7c9201c0 ffffffff
0x03e9f898:   7c9201bb 7c3416b3 003f0000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x03d337d9)
0x03d337c9:   e0 e9 cd 21 fa ff b1 37 d3 03 bb 37 d3 03 c5 37
0x03d337d9:   d3 03 89 37 d3 03 93 37 d3 03 9d 37 d3 03 a7 37 


Stack: [0x03e50000,0x03ea0000],  sp=0x03e9f828,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x637d9]
J  javafish.clients.opc.JOpc.getDownloadGroupNative()Ljavafish/clients/opc/component/OpcGroup;
J  javafish.clients.opc.JEasyOpc.run()V
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  javafish.clients.opc.JOpc.getDownloadGroupNative()Ljavafish/clients/opc/component/OpcGroup;
J  javafish.clients.opc.JEasyOpc.run()V
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x03573400 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_in_native, id=5864, stack(0x03e50000,0x03ea0000)]
  0x03555400 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5384, stack(0x03c80000,0x03cd0000)]
  0x03552400 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4144, stack(0x03c30000,0x03c80000)]
  0x003f6400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=5848, stack(0x008d0000,0x00920000)]
  0x034d7400 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=528, stack(0x03a30000,0x03a80000)]
  0x034cd400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5408, stack(0x03970000,0x039c0000)]
  0x034bd800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=2228, stack(0x03920000,0x03970000)]
  0x0348d400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6108, stack(0x038d0000,0x03920000)]
  0x02e7f400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5700, stack(0x030d0000,0x03120000)]
  0x02e79c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5816, stack(0x03080000,0x030d0000)]
  0x02e78c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1652, stack(0x03030000,0x03080000)]
  0x02e77c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5108, stack(0x02fe0000,0x03030000)]
  0x02e66800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3508, stack(0x02f90000,0x02fe0000)]
  0x02e65400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4232, stack(0x02f40000,0x02f90000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02e60c00 VMThread [stack: 0x02ef0000,0x02f40000] [id=4324]
  0x02e91400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03120000,0x03170000] [id=4920]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 960K, used 360K [0x10020000, 0x10120000, 0x14d00000)
  eden space 896K,  38% used [0x10020000, 0x10075f18, 0x10100000)
  from space 64K,  26% used [0x10110000, 0x10114328, 0x10120000)
  to   space 64K,   0% used [0x10100000, 0x10100000, 0x10110000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 2372K [0x14d00000, 0x15100000, 0x4e820000)
   the space 4096K,  57% used [0x14d00000, 0x14f511a8, 0x14f51200, 0x15100000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 11366K [0x4e820000, 0x4f420000, 0x52820000)
   the space 12288K,  92% used [0x4e820000, 0x4f339b30, 0x4f339c00, 0x4f420000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00423000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c910000 - 0x7c9c5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c903000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77e4c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e50000 - 0x77ee2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fc0000 - 0x77fd1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e390000 - 0x7e421000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77f39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76340000 - 0x7635d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x10000000 - 0x10017000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\APSHook.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7c0000 - 0x6da10000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b00000 - 0x76b2e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d270000 - 0x6d278000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bbb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d770000 - 0x6d77c000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\verify.dll
0x6d310000 - 0x6d32f000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\java.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bf000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\zip.dll
0x6d570000 - 0x6d583000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\net.dll
0x71a30000 - 0x71a47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77be0000 - 0x77c38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x71a20000 - 0x71a28000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x719d0000 - 0x71a10000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x66740000 - 0x66799000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a10000 - 0x71a18000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f07000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76d20000 - 0x76d39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x76f70000 - 0x76f78000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f4d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x76f86000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x76630000 - 0x766e5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x597f0000 - 0x59845000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d750000 - 0x6d758000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x77a50000 - 0x77ae6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77af0000 - 0x77b02000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d12e000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\awt.dll
0x72f80000 - 0x72fa6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x774b0000 - 0x775ed000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x5b150000 - 0x5b188000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x736e0000 - 0x7372b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ddraw.dll
0x73b40000 - 0x73b46000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x6d210000 - 0x6d263000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x746b0000 - 0x746fc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x75160000 - 0x7518e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x7e6a0000 - 0x7eec1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x77f40000 - 0x77fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x774a3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\comctl32.dll
0x58c30000 - 0x58cca000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll
0x6d590000 - 0x6d599000     C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin\nio.dll
0x03cd0000 - 0x03d4c000     C:\Documents and Settings\ingenieria\Escritorio\JEasyOpc\lib\JCustomOpc.dll
0x770f0000 - 0x7717b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\oleaut32.dll
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bd8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\version.dll
0x590d0000 - 0x590d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wship6.dll
0x76f90000 - 0x7700f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77010000 - 0x770e0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x03ea0000 - 0x04176000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x03ac0000 - 0x03acc000     C:\Archivos de programa\Rockwell Software\RSLinx\RSOPCCON.DLL
0x0c390000 - 0x0c7d1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msi.dll
0x79000000 - 0x79045000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCOREE.DLL
0x60610000 - 0x60616000     c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\fusion.dll
0x78130000 - 0x781cb000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_x-ww_6b128700\MSVCR80.dll
0x79e70000 - 0x7a3d4000     c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
0x0c860000 - 0x0c87a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\opcproxy.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1000m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: Controlador.motor
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Archivos de programa/Java/jre1.6.0_07/bin/client;C:/Archivos de programa/Java/jre1.6.0_07/bin;C:/Archivos de programa/Java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/i386;C:\Archivos de programa\Rockwell Software\RSCommon;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Archivos de programa\Intel\DMIX;c:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Archivos de programa\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\;C:\Archivos de programa\Hewlett-Packard\IAM\bin;C:\Archivos de programa\Siemens\FactoryLink\Common;C:\Archivos de programa\Siemens\Factorylink\Server\BIN;C:\Archivos de programa\Rockwell Automation\Common\Components;C:\Documents and Settings\ingenieria\Escritorio\eclipse;
USERNAME=ingenieria
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 7 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2097151k(2018032k free), swap 4194303k(3802640k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b23) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_07-b06), built on Jun 10 2008 01:14:11 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Thu Apr 17 00:11:58 2014
elapsed time: 22087 seconds
```

Comment: "The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code." in WinXP? You're in bad situation... If it's not a known problem, the only option is to change Java and OS versions. Or hardware. No, really, this could be even a hardware bug - try differentiating it with something like memtest.

Comment: It may be worth reporting this to JeasyOPC on their [bug system](http://sourceforge.net/p/jeasyopc/bugs/) There does seem to have been a similar problem in the past.